# How do I properly handle timestamps using CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, datetime, timezone, timestamp, cakephp-2.0

Please feel free to only answer parts of the question, whatever you might have an answer to.

With the new 2.2 version of cake, time zones are better supported, which is perfect timing since I'm working on a very "time sensitive" app.  Try as I might though, I simply cannot get everything to work.  So here are my questions:

Should datetime entries (think created/modified) be stored in UTC?  If so, what's the most effecient way to make sure cake uses UTC?

Should timestamps (precise moments in time) be stored as an int or as a timestamp in mysql?

Using the new cake, how do I automatically convert UTC int/timestamps to a default site timezone?  A user timezone (stored in their user tuple)?

If datetime (created/modified) times are stored as UTC, how do I convert them using cake to the default site timezone?  User timezone?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you want to customize the time settings for your site users, then you should use a global time setting i.e. UTC format. Save in UTC format into the database. In your app/Config/core.php, you will find the following line.

   ```
   date_default_timezone_set('UTC');  // at line 232
   ```

   So you can confirm that cake will use the UTC time format while saving time into the database.
2. The following items summarize TIMESTAMP initialization and updating properties prior to MySQL 4.1.2:

   The first TIMESTAMP column in table row automatically is set to the current timestamp when the record is created if the column is set to NULL or is not specified at all.

   The first TIMESTAMP column in table row automatically is updated to the current timestamp when the value of any other column in the row is changed, unless the TIMESTAMP column explicitly is assigned a value other than NULL.

   If a DEFAULT value is specified for the first TIMESTAMP column when the table is created, it is silently ignored.

   Other TIMESTAMP columns in the table can be set to the current TIMESTAMP by assigning NULL to them, but they do not update automatically.

What I think, it should better to save timestamp in an integer field if you don't want to change it automatically.

Comment: Thanks for your response, that definitely narrows the questions some.  I did discover that avoiding the automatic features of `TIMESTAMP` is really pretty easy (allowing the field to be null), but I agree this automatic behavior complicates things... and seems really poorly thought out.  A definite solid consideration.

As for the first portion, that helps with that part.  Thanks!